# The oldest common ancesstor of all human beings

Tags: evolution, palaeontology

Do all human beings have a single oldest ancestor (a man and a woman), or were there were many ancestors at the same time at different places on earth? 
[This article](http://news.discovery.com/animals/dinosaurs/life-single-common-ancestor.htm) sheds some light. Is there another authoritative report released more recently?

Comment: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/what-is-a-mitochondrial-eve-and-y-chromosomal-adam covers much of the same material.

Comment: Isn't that Adam? ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Mitochondrial Eve and Y-chromosomal Adam](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/7184/what-is-a-mitochondrial-eve-and-y-chromosomal-adam)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The MRCA is different from mtEve and YcAdam.

Answer (score 3):

You are talking about the [mitochondrial eve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitochondrial_Eve) and the chromosome Y adam.  At some point there must be just one pair, though historically the evidence can be lost if there is a near complete extinction event.  Current evidence for eve points to SE Africa.